# Calculate average fuel last 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, average

I have a script that calculates the aveage fuel consumption the last 30 days, but some users are reporting errors in the calculation.

This is what I've got:

```
//Calculate the total km for the last 30 days
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MIN(km) AS minikm, MAX(km) AS maxkm FROM diesel WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx' AND userid = ".$_COOKIE['userid']." ORDER BY diesel.dato DESC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ $mileage = $row['maxkm'] - $row['minikm'];}

//Sum up all the Liters of diesel
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(liter) AS totalfuel FROM diesel WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx' AND userid = ".$_COOKIE['userid']." ORDER BY diesel.dato DESC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ $totalfuel = $row['totalfuel'];} 

$averagefuel = $totalfuel / $mileage * 10;
```

When troubleshooting this I noticed I should not include the liters in the first record in the calculation. Only the total kms. So How can I do that ?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: sorry, the jquery tag came up my a mistake.

Comment: Maybe it's not related to the question, but be aware of SQL Injection (the $_Cookie part for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to speculate on what the users are thinking, the problem is that the fuel inputs over a month are somewhat unrelated to the fuel consumption during the month.  In other words, the tank may start empty full or somewhere in-between.  And, it might end empty, full, or somewhere in-between.

That means that your calculation can be off by up to a tank-full of fuel on either side.

Now, this could be mitigated by particular circumstances.  For instance, perhaps the vehicles are being driven every day, with their fuel tanks filled at the end of the day.  So, at midnight, you have a reasonable assumption that the tanks are full.  I would be surprised if this were the case, because the inventory of fuel in the cars costs money.  They could hire me as a consultant to improve their balance sheet ;)  (just for the record, that is not my specialty).

As a small note, you can do the full calculations in SQL.  You don't need to use two queries or any client side calculations:

```
SELECT 10 * SUM(liter) / (MAX(km) - MIN(km)) as AvgFuel
FROM diesel
WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx' AND userid = ".$_COOKIE['userid'].";
```

Comment: That looks way better than my queries. I will try that. This is a small web application for the drivers in our trucking company. We always fill our tanks full. Daily or every 2nd day. When I compare my average fuel consumption with the one I'm using on my iPhone I see there are one difference in the calculation. The difference is that the iphone app does not include the liters of diesel in the first record picked by the sql query. Mine does, but what is correct ? my web app or the iphone app ? :)

Comment: @RogerAndersen . . . Probably somewhere in-between.  The first "fill" after a given date might be for fuel used entirely before the date, after the date, or somewhere in-between.  Given your business practices, you might be able to figure that out.  On Stack Overflow, that would be a different question, with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need all the time add $mileage. Try this:

```
//Calculate the total km for the last 30 days
$mileage = 0;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MIN(km) AS minikm, MAX(km) AS maxkm FROM diesel WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx' AND userid = ".$_COOKIE['userid']." ORDER BY diesel.dato DESC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ $mileage += $row['maxkm'] - $row['minikm'];}

//Sum up all the Liters of diesel
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(liter) AS totalfuel FROM diesel WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx' AND userid = ".$_COOKIE['userid']." ORDER BY diesel.dato DESC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ $totalfuel = $row['totalfuel'];} 

$averagefuel = $totalfuel / $mileage * 10;
```

Gordon Linoff provide to you good solution. Try to use this:

```
//Calculate the total km for the last 30 days
$mileage = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,
"SELECT 10 * SUM(liter) / (MAX(km) - MIN(km)) as AvgFuel
FROM diesel
WHERE diesel.dato >= '$dx' AND userid = ".$_COOKIE['userid']);
$averagefuel = $steps = 0; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $averagefuel += $row['AvgFuel']; 
    $steps++; 
} 
$averagefuel = $averagefuel/$steps;
```

Comment: I noticed when troubleshooting that I should not include the liters in the first record. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is first record? Can you add what data you get in troubleshooting, I don't really understand you. Also Gordon Linoff provide to you good solution. You need to use his query then 
$averagefuel = $steps = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$averagefuel += $row['AvgFuel'];
$steps++;
}
$averagefuel = $averagefuel/$steps;

Comment: I was using an iphone app that caluclates for me and its showing different values that what I get. I always expected that app to be correct, but maybe I'm wrong. The app calculates the same way as I do  here, but it does not include the liters in the first record that appears in the sql query. Mine does.

Comment: Then you need to check it by yourself for some little interval, we have not enough data for help in this case.